# Image from TWebBrowser to TPicture

Tags: delphi, winapi, rendering, delphi-xe2, twebbrowser

How to get an image that has been downloaded in TWebBrowser to a TPicture without copying it to clipboard or looking in to cache contents.

Comment: If you just want to download an image (or any other file) from the web, that's very easy. (Much easier than using a `TWebBrowser`). But I guess you have your reasons?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand i updated my question. I found a c# solution. But would need to someone to translate.

Comment: `DrawToDC` is deprecated, see [MSDN DOC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752273%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Also this SO question: [How to render WebBrowser to device context?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10884088/576719).

Comment: @LURD not quite the same question he want to render whole page.

Comment: That question illustrates the problem with the deprecated `DrawToDC`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ok i made sample with last answer to you :

fisrt get image with this function by Id :

```
function GetImgElementById(const Doc: IDispatch; const id : string): IHTMLImgElement;
var
  Document: IHTMLDocument2;     // IHTMLDocument2 interface of Doc
  Body: IHTMLElement2;          // document body element
  Tags: IHTMLElementCollection; // all tags in document body
  Tag: IHTMLElement;            // a tag in document body
  I: Integer;                   // loops thru tags in document body
begin

  Result :=nil ;
  // Check for valid document: require IHTMLDocument2 interface to it
  if not Supports(Doc, IHTMLDocument2, Document) then
    raise Exception.Create('Invalid HTML document');
  // Check for valid body element: require IHTMLElement2 interface to it
  if not Supports(Document.body, IHTMLElement2, Body) then
    raise Exception.Create('Can''t find <body> element');
  // Get all tags in body element ('*' => any tag name)
  Tags := Body.getElementsByTagName('img');
  // Scan through all tags in body
  for I := 0 to Pred(Tags.length) do
  begin
    // Get reference to a tag
    Tag := Tags.item(I, EmptyParam) as IHTMLElement;
    // Check tag's id and return it if id matches
    if AnsiSameText(Tag.id, id) then
    begin
      Result := Tag as IHTMLImgElement ;
      Break;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

after you can use it :

```
var
  img : IHTMLImgElement ;
  rnd : IHTMLElementRender ;
begin
  //
  img := GetImgElementById(wb1.Document,'imgid');
  // img1 is TImage
  img1.Height := img.height ;
  img1.Width := img.width ;
  rnd := img as IHTMLElementRender ;
  rnd.DrawToDC(img1.Canvas.Handle);
end;
```

dont forget "MSHTML" unit ;

Comment: Is it possible to modify the function based on src attribute? tag=AnsiContainsStr('imagehostname.com')

<img id="Id" style="display: inline; width: 218px; height: 48px;" src="http://imagehostname.com?u=235235235235235">

Comment: you can get info with Tag.getAttribute('src') in if function

Comment: Can this be used with the indy IdHttp?

Comment: No, you can't use direct this way , you must passing result to `TWebBrowser` .